# Gravity Forms and WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

Our team is working on a WooCommerce project for one of our clients.

They are event organizers and work with volunteers who sell tickets on their behalf.

They do not want volunteers to have access to the backend of their site, so we are trying to find a way to create an order form using Gravity Forms that will record the sale as desired and communicate product depletions to the Product database in WooCommerce.

Any thoughts on how this might be accomplished?

Comment: This isn't exactly a specific programming question and sounds more like a full-scale project. What you're describing sounds a bit like "point of sale". Have you checked out any of the POS plugins for WooCommerce?

Comment: BTW- Not WooCommerce, but check out http://eventespresso.com/features/mobile-ticketing-apps/